# Conditionally simulating exceptions/return values when testing Axis 1.4 SOAP calls

Tags: java, spring, exception, junit, axis

Apologies for the longwinded question...

In order to test business logic which calls Axis 1.4 web services in my unit tests, I'm currently using a Spring proxy which allows me to set exceptions and simulate return values as per below.

However, I was wondering whether there was a cleaner way of doing this:

In my JUnit application context I introduce the following advice:

```
<bean id="testProxy" class="appl.service.TestProxyImpl" />
<bean id="testAdvice" class="org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultIntroductionAdvisor">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="testProxy"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="appl.service.ITestProxy"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator">
    <property name="beanNames" value="myAxisProxy"/>
    <property name="interceptorNames" value="testAdvice"/>
</bean>
```

The TestProxyImpl class is as follows (let me know if you need to see the interface):

```
public class TestProxyImpl 
    extends DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor 
    implements ITestProxy {

    private Map<String, Integer> calls = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    private Map<String, Throwable[]> exceptions = new HashMap<String, Throwable[]>();
    private Map<String, Object> returnValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    private Map<String, Object[]> lastParams = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();

    public int getCalls(String methodName) {
        Integer noCalls = calls.get(methodName);
        if (noCalls == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return noCalls;
    }

    public void resetCalls() {
        calls.clear();
        returnValues.clear();
        exceptions.clear();
        lastParams.clear();
    }

    public void addExceptions(String method, Throwable... exceptions) {
        this.exceptions.put(method, exceptions);
    }

    public void addReturnValue(String method, Object result) {
        returnValues.put(method, result);
    } 

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T getLastParameter(String method, Class<? extends T> paramClass) {
        Object[] args = lastParams.get(method);
        if (args != null) {
            for (Object arg : args) {
                if (arg != null) {
                    if (paramClass.isAssignableFrom(arg.getClass())) {
                        return (T)arg;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doProceed(MethodInvocation mi) throws Throwable {
        String methodName = mi.getMethod().getName();
        int noCalls;
        synchronized (calls) {
            noCalls = getCalls(methodName);
            calls.put(methodName, noCalls + 1);
        }
        Object[] args = mi.getArguments();
        synchronized (lastParams) {
            lastParams.put(methodName, args);
        }
        if (exceptions.containsKey(methodName)) {
            Throwable[] exceptionArray = exceptions.get(methodName);
            if (exceptionArray != null) {
                Throwable e = exceptionArray[noCalls % exceptionArray.length];
                if (e != null) {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
        if (returnValues.containsKey(methodName)) {
            return returnValues.get(methodName);
        }
        return super.doProceed(mi);
    }
}
```

which allows me to use the following unit tests:

```
protected void onSetUp() throws Exception {
    super.onSetUp();

    // testProxy is autowired into the unit test class
    testProxy.resetCalls();
}

public void testSuccess() throws Exception {

    // myBusinessObject is autowired into the unit test class
    // myAxisProxy is injected into myBusinessObject in the spring context
    // myBusinessObject calls myAxisProxy.myMethod(MyRequestObject) internally
    myBusinessObject.doSomething();

    // check that myAxisProxy has been called the correct times
    // with the correct parameters
    assertEquals(1, testProxy.getCalls("myMethod"));
    assertEquals(
        "foo", 
        testProxy.getLastParameter(
            "myMethod", 
             MyRequestObject.class).getMyField());
 }

 public void testWithoutCallingProxy() throws Exception {

     testProxy.addReturnValue("myMethod", createTestReturnValues());

     myBusinessObject.doSomething();

     // check that the response is as expected
 }

 public void testWithException() throws Exception {
     testProxy.addException(
         "myMethod", 
         AxisFault.makeFault(new ConnectException("test")),
         null);

     // this would check that the first call results in a ConnectException
     // simulating a network error, but myBusinessObject retries
     // and goes through to the service on the second call.
     myBusinessObject.doSomething();
 }
```

I've briefly looked into EasyMock, but was not sure how I'd be able to create a mock object that intercepts the call and returns an exception or specified return values some of the time, but uses the correct call some other times, so was wondering whether anyone had ideas on how to simplify this.

Note, ideally I'd like to avoid having to rewire the properties of `myBusinessObject`.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I'm using Spring 2.5, JUnit 3.8 and Axis 1.4

EDIT2:

I'm using this approach to automate integration tests, rather than simple unit tests, so I'm any suggestions on how to replace the handcrafted solution with something based on a library are most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical layered development should be organized something like below:

> ### Data Access
>
> ### Business Logic
>
> ### Service Interface

This again should remind that when developing repeatable independent unit tests that your tests should target logic and functionality in its intended layer and component ONLY.  Thus when testing Business Logic I do not want to make actual service calls at all, I don't even want to make Data Access calls either, that is why we use Mocking frameworks like EasyMock.

If you don't like EasyMock then try looking at Mockito.  It has a few more features for dealing with code that is less than ideal for mocking.

And I find it strange that you would go to so much trouble to avoid a little rewiring.  It is well worth the refactoring effort.

Comment: I agree with the layered development approach (and I've got a number of independent test as well).  The main reason for the approach of not rewiring is to automate the end-to-end test as I've been bitten by not doing such a test a number of times (due to different teams working on different components).  And as "myBusinessObject" contains a number of different "myAxisProxy" objects, this approach made it easier to test a number of different scenarios (e.g. myAxisProxy1 fails but myAxisProxy to is ok, etc) without having to redo the wiring for "myBusinessObject".  Does that make sense?

Comment: @beny23, Perfect sense, you need end-to-end (integration) tests but you also need unit tests as well.  If you happen to work in a situation where other teams have components that break all the time then while the integration tests tell you that its broken, unit tests will tell you that YOUR components are fine!  They are significant leverage for you to print a test run out of your component and PROVE that there is not a problem in your code.  It is all about CYA.  You adding a considerable complexity to your integration tests it seems because you are getting "bitten" by the mistakes of others?

Comment: I like the approach and it makes sense, but like I said before I think at that point you end up testing functionality in other peoples components when the integration tests should be testing that everything was deployed correctly to a specific environment end-to-end. Do you understand the difference? It is as if the other component developers are not doing an adequate job of testing their components so you are essentially testing their functionality for them just because you are getting blamed for it. This is an anti-pattern that the higher level component consumer gets the blame for problems.

Comment: Hehe, tell me about it, the running joke in our team is that if the internet is broken, people will point the finger at our components.  But seriously, we've sometimes got situations where testing resources are scarce and different teams "forget" to test the whole applications, leaving us with support calls for when the business logic breaks because somebody took shortcuts with the regression testing.  So, I'm going to have a look on whether I can make use of EasyMock and Mockito to replace my handcrafted solution. Thanks.

Comment: `we've sometimes got situations where testing resources are scarce and different teams "forget" to test the whole applications`  Unit testing of code is a development task, not a QA task.  It is not a matter of "testing resources", it is a problem of "developer laziness" and/or "management giving impossible deadlines".  `because somebody took shortcuts with the regression testing.` If they had written proper unit tests then regression testing is as easy as clicking a mouse.  But I digress.  You are not alone trust me.  Keep fighting the good fight.